# Disable a button when the selected file from the javascript file browser is loading on the browser

Tags: javascript

I have a screen where a file is selected using file browser and user clicks on **Upload** button to save the data onto a database.

1. The problem is that when I select a huge file (Say of 10MB), the browser hangs till the file is loaded onto the browser cache.
2. Meanwhile user clicks on the Upload button multiple times, and the multiple sever calls will be made to save the data.

I want to know is there a way I can disable the Upload button until the selected file is loaded on the browser and only then user should be allowed to click on Upload button.

I am using Chrome browser (72.0.X version).

I have tried attaching load even to the file object. But the event isn't getting fired.

My code:

```js
var fileObj = document.getElementById('file')
fileObj.addEventListener("load", function() {
  // do some stuffs...
});
```

```html
<input name="file" type="file" id="file" multiple=false />
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Uploading files has many steps to make it easy for the customer, and illustrate the process so the user don´t hit the upload button again. I would recommend using a javascript upload framework that handles the process and handles most of the edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert `document.getElementById("file").hidden= "true"` within the load-Function!
Then you have to use the XMLHttpRequest.loadend to reset the hidden-Status of the element. But note from [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/upload):

> This event does not differentiate between success or failure, and is sent at the end of the upload regardless of the outcome. Prior to this event, one of load, error, abort, or timeout will already have been delivered to indicate why the upload ended.

```js
var client = null;
var fileObj = document.getElementById('file');
fileObj.addEventListener("load", function() {
    document.getElementById("file").hidden= "true";
    client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.loadend = function(e) {
        document.getElementById("file").hidden= "false";
        // do some further stuffs...
    };
  // do some stuffs...
});
```

```html
<input name="file" type="file" id="file" multiple=false />
```